# How do I copy images in Firefox for Android/Fennec?

Tags: images, firefox-for-android, copy-paste

I'm using Firefox for Android (also called Fennec) v.46 on Android Kit-Kat 4.4.2.

When I tap-and-hold on images in a browser in Android, I get a context-sensitive menu, as expected.

However, the menu in Fennec doesn't include an option to just copy the image to the Android clipboard (or do whatever it would normally do behind the scenes, such as producing a URI for the image). This is what I see:

[image: Context-sensitive menu when clicking-and-holding on an image in Fennec]

The options available are:

- Share Image
- Copy Image Location
- Save Image
- Set Image As

I'm not interested in possible work-arounds in this particular case i.e. saving the image then importing it into another app is not a workflow I want to deal with.

I have two questions, then:

- **Is there something I'm missing that will enable me to copy images in Fennec?**
- **If not, did Fennec ever support the copying of images, having removed it later due to bugs/instability/security issues?**

Comment: I don't remember it ever having a "copy image" option, but that's hardly conclusive. Copy/paste of objects other than text is not used by a lot of Android apps.

Comment: You're right, it is conspicuously absent from multiple browsers. It's not present in the most recent versions of Chrome or Chromium either. However, I have seen and used it in older versions of Chrome, so it's not something that's not possible at all within Android.